# How to redirect 301 in nginx?

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

I want people type in http://myweb.com/watch/fadfadf1 will redirect to http://myweb.com/watch-1/fadfadf1
I want change "watch" to "watch-1"
Please help me. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

```
rewrite ^/watch/fadfadf1$ http://myweb.com/watch-1/fadfadf1 permanent;
```